# Not able to load $http.get - JSON data in ui tabset child tabs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I tried to load a dropdown with the response got from http post. But its failing to load on child tabs.

When i click next button from tab1. I make a post call and get a JSON back. Using the returned data i want to load a dropdown in my second tab.

I already raised a query on tabset and it worked fine. Now I modified the plunker little bit. I did the same way mentioned in the below link. But i'm missing something when i try to do the samething with $http.get

[Tabset $rootScope scope not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707365/tabset-rootscope-scope-not-updating)

**app.js**

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.service('Common', function() {
  this.tabData = {};
})

.controller('SampleController', function($scope, $http, Common) {
  $scope.submitTab1 = function() {
    $http.get("post.json", {
      // Some logic
    }).success(function(data) {
      Common.tabData = data;
      $scope.steps.step2 = true;
    });
  }
})

.controller("SampleTab2Controller", function($scope, Common) {
  $scope.userList = Common.tabData;
});
```

**Html**

```
  <tabset ng-init="steps={step1:true, step2:false}"> 

   <tab heading="Step 1" active="steps.step1">
    <div data-ng-controller="SampleController">      
      <form data-ng-submit="submitTab1()">
           <label>Some Operations ...</label>
           <br>
           <br>
           <label>Click next to retrieve json from server  ...</label>
          <button type="submit">Click Next</button>
      </form>
    </div>    
    </tab>

    <tab heading="Step 2" active="steps.step2">
    <div data-ng-controller="SampleTab2Controller">
      <form name="step2">
         <p>load the json list from Tab1 controller </p>
        <select ng-model="selectedUser" ng-options="user.title for user in userList">
          <option value="">--- select ---</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      </div>
    </tab>

  </tabset>
```

**Post.json**

```
[
   {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Arnold"
   },
   {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "stallone"
   }
]
```

Plunker Code http://plnkr.co/edit/EZC1d6tDDZlpWZUHY6os?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue has nothing to do with loading from http, but it has to do with properly copying reference of objects.

When you do `$scope.userList = Common.tabData;` the reference of tabData is copied to userList, and then when the tabData is updated using `Common.tabData = data` now tabData in the service points to a different reference and `$scope.userList` keeps pointing to the old one. So instead of getting the reference of tabData and copying it to the userList, set up the service object itself on the scope.

In your controller change `$scope.userList = Common.tabData` to `$scope.userList = Common` :-

```
.controller("SampleTab2Controller", function($scope, Common) {
  $scope.userList = Common;
});
```

and in the view iterate upon `userList.tabData`

```
  <select ng-model="selectedUser" ng-options="user.title for user in userList.tabData">
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7nBYbg?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

If I modified your code this way it works

1) changed tabData to be an array
2) Used angular.copy instead of asignning

```
.service('Common', function() {
  this.tabData = [];  ==> Changed this to array
})


$http.get("post.json", {
        // Some logic
}).success(function(data) {
    angular.copy(data,Common.tabData);  ==> Used angular copy so it copies the array
    $scope.steps.step2 = true; 
});
```

Updated [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8n3hzMNtFVk47huJGeZn?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

main issue in your code is controller get executed first and then Common.tabData is loaded.so can do like this:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap'])

.service('Common', function() {
  this.tabData = {};
})

.controller('SampleController', function($scope,$http, Common) {
  $scope.submitTab1 = function() {
            $http.get("post.json", {
                // Some logic
            }).success(function(data) {
                Common.tabData = data;
                $scope.steps.step2 = true; 
            });
        }
})

.controller("SampleTab2Controller", function($scope, Common) {
  $scope.userList = Common;

});
```

and html code according to this is:

```
<div data-ng-controller="SampleTab2Controller">
      <form name="step2">
         <p>load the json list from Tab1 controller </p>
        <select ng-model="selectedUser" ng-options="user.title for user in userList.tabData">
          <option value="">--- select ---</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      </div>
```