# Have radios in one controller hide/show an element in another controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to connect some functionality between controllers. Basically I want a div to hide/show based on what radio is selected in a different controller.

With a little help I managed to get this working part of the way. Here's what I have so far.

I set up a factory to bridge communication between the 2 controllers where I have an update function that is fired upon `ng-change` to update the string with the new desired one.

```
.factory("sessionCheck", function() {
    var sessionCheck = {};
    var update = function (index) {
        console.log(index);
        sessionCheck = index; 
        return sessionCheck;
    };
    return { update: update }
```

So in the first controller will call the function when `ng-change` occurs on the radios, like so:

```
//bring in session check, (injected above)
$scope.updateChecker = sessionCheck;

$scope.sessionChange = function(){
    $scope.updateChecker.update($scope.opMeasure);
};
```

So this works fine if I `console.log` the index in the change function in the factory. So where I'm struggling is pulling this information into another controller and using it to `ng-hide` (or show) a div.

It would also be cool if there was a default value of "1" returning before the ng-change fired. It would be even better if there is an easier way that directly reads off of the radios' model (opMeasure) instead of firing off the `ng-change` of the radios.

Been struggling with this for a few hours, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!

Comment: define a property on your `sessionCheck` and use it as the expression for your `ng-hide` directive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered a similar **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25707365/tabset-rootscope-scope-not-updating/25707487#25707487)** yesterday. You can do this by sharing a common data object reference across your controllers using a common service.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/o0FDonOLvLLNLGtyr7rG?p=preview)**

*JAVASCRIPT*

```
angular.module('demo', [])

  .factory('SessionCheck', function() {
    var sessionCheck = {
      data: {}
    };

    // default value
    sessionCheck.data.selection = 1;

    return sessionCheck;
  })

  .controller('Ctrl1', function($scope, SessionCheck) {
    $scope.data = SessionCheck.data;
  })

  .controller('Ctrl2', function($scope, SessionCheck) {
    $scope.data = SessionCheck.data;
  });
```

*HTML*

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1">
  <h1>Controller 1</h1>
  Measurement:
  <select ng-model="data.selection">
    <option value="">-- Select</option>
    <option value="1">1 Meter</option>
    <option value="2">2 Meters</option>
    <option value="3">3 Meters</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
  <h1>Controller 2</h1>
  <div ng-show="data.selection == 1">
    1 Meter items
  </div>

  <div ng-show="data.selection == 2">
    2 Meter items
  </div>

  <div ng-show="data.selection == 3">
    3 Meter items
  </div>
</div>
```